# Multithreading app that lauches and monitor another executable

Tags: multithreading, fork, execvp

I found a code that launches a code using fork and execvp

but then by digging the web I realized it was not compatible with multithreading

so now I am quiet confused...

"the Pthreads standard specifies that an exec call from any thread must terminate all threads in the process and start a single new thread at main in the new image."

I definetely need multithreading, so in that context how do I launch an external executable, check if it is running and occasionaly kill it ?

thanks

Comment: nobody ? this is areal honest question , every time I check in google "multithread exec", people talk about fork, so how do I exec in a mutithread program ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'll use system() then, thanks for the wonderfull support

[comments dont work anymore]